# What is the name of the significance test scipy.stats.pearsonr is using?

Tags: statistical-significance, scipy

The [Notes section](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) in the docs describes it in detail but does not name it. I would like to avoid guessing.

They use a beta distribution in this way:

```
dist = scipy.stats.beta(n/2 - 1, n/2 - 1, loc=-1, scale=2)
p = 2*dist.cdf(-abs(r))
```

Comment: It doesn't have a name, really.  it's just a test based on the asymptotic distribution of the correlation coefficient when the underlying variables have independent Normal distributions.